# livewire datatable columns sort not restoring after page refresh

Tags: datatables, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, columnsorting, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I am working on laravel livewire datatables. when change sorting of table, after refresh the page sorting not removed. I need to completely refresh page & show original datatable results when refreshing page.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="table-responsivemt-2">
<livewire:table.admin-match :params="['filter' => $this->filter]"/>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]